# Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to Chrome's 'pin tab' feature?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to pin a tab in Chrome.

[image]

**Is this possible?**

Comment: What kind of shortcut @Aron? Like a keyboard shortcut or ...?

Comment: @Ivo, yeah a keyboard shortcut. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: You could file a request, but I wouldn’t hold my breath. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1d9aaf475675ac08&hl=en)
, it does not seem possible:

Maybe with some kind of extension it is possible, like also mentioned in that thread, [Shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf). But it doesn't seem up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered [this](https://github.com/os0x/ChromeKeyconfig) extension, which, among other few things, has a shortcut for toggle pin tabs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a very simple [Tab Pinner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-pinner-keyboard-short/mbcjcnomlakhkechnbhmfjhnnllpbmlh/details) extension that gives you just that - the shortcut to pin/unpin tab action. It doesn't have any settings page of it's own - it uses Extensions settings page at the bottom of which you can set shortcuts for your extensions.

Very useful. I got used to CTRL+SHIFT+P on Opera 12.

Answer (score 0):

There is not standard shortcut right now. But you can right click on tab and press 'p'. This does the same. This method is comparatively easier.